# Pointers in C/C++ compiles but gives segfault error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Here's a code snipped that I have for a larger program

```
double *pos_x_h[224];
double *pos_y_h[224];
const double A = 1;         
const int N = 224;
double d_0;       
double alpha;     


void initialize(double nu, int rows = 16, int columns = 14) {  
    double d = 1 / double(columns);
    d_0 = d * (1 - pow(2.0, nu - 8));
    alpha = d - d_0;
    double dx = d;
    double dy = d * sqrt(3.0) / 2;

    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            int n = i + j * columns;
            *pos_x_h[n] = i * dx + (j % 2) * dx / 2.0;
            *pos_y_h[n] = j * dy;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double nu=7.5;
    int rows=16;
    int columns=14;

    initialize(nu);

return 0;
}
```

The code compiles but it is gives a seg fault error. Can't see why that's the case. Am I going over array_size?

Comment: `i + j * columns` would clearly access elements beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: `void initialize(double nu, int rows=16,int columns=14);` and `initialize(nu);`?

Comment: You declare 2 arrays of pointers but never initialize them.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any point in utilizing `pos_x_h` and `pos_y_h` as pointer arrays.

**Change this:**

```
double *pos_x_h[224];
double *pos_y_h[224];
```

**To this:**

```
double pos_x_h[224];
double pos_y_h[224];
```

**And this:**

```
*pos_x_h[n] = i * dx + (j % 2) * dx / 2.0;
*pos_y_h[n] = j * dy;
```

**To this:**

```
pos_x_h[n] = i * dx + (j % 2) * dx / 2.0;
pos_y_h[n] = j * dy;
```

If you really insist on utilizing pointer arrays, then you can use this (in addition to the above):

```
double *pos_x_h_ptr[224];
double *pos_y_h_ptr[224];
for (int n=0; n<224; n++)
{
    pos_x_h_ptr[n] = pos_x_h+n;
    pos_y_h_ptr[n] = pos_y_h+n;
}
```

Comment: This is a section of a larger code. Those arrays need to be pointers in this case.

Comment: @MisterSpock, every entry in the array has an address. If you just need to pass the address of entry `i` in array `pos_x_h` to `func()` for example, then you can do it simply by calling `func(pos_x_h+i)` or `func(&pos_x_h[i])`. Alternatively, you can initialize two arrays of pointers, and fill them with the addresses of the entries of these `pos_x_h` and `pos_y_h` arrays. For example (on one array only): `double* ptr_array[224]; for (i=0; i<224; i++) ptr_array[i] = pos_x_h+i;`.

Comment: it says cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ in assignment. Pointers are killing me, I'm a n00b in c/c++ it seems.

Comment: @MisterSpock, I said "add this", meaning that you should also apply the other stuff that I wrote in the answer.

Comment: gives me an invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘double*’. I'll start from scratch in the morning and give an update.

Answer (score 1):

```
double *pos_x_h[224];
double *pos_y_h[224];
```

are arrays of pointers, but you use them wihtout allocating memory

```
*pos_x_h[n] = i * dx + (j % 2) * dx / 2.0;
*pos_y_h[n] = j * dy;
```

probably something like that

```
 pos_x_h[n] = malloc(sizeof(double));
 *pos_x_h[n] = i * dx + (j % 2) * dx / 2.0;
 pos_y_h[n] = malloc(sizeof(double));
 *pos_y_h[n] = j * dy;
```

if you need to alocate memory outside the initialize function (why would you? it is init function) you can do it in main

```
  int i = 0;
  for(;i< 224;++i)
  {
      pos_x_h[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
      pos_y_h[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
  }
```

Comment: Ah. Now, it throws me an error saying that I have an error in converting void to double in function initialize (lines for alpha, and d_0). Also, would it be possible to allocate memory while declaring the pointer/outside initialize function?

Comment: @MisterSpock i don't understand at wich lines exactly you get errors. Lines i added, with malloc? Then you probably using C++ compiler and not C. in such case you better use operator `new`, or add cast to double. To init them outside your function  you should allocate memory in loop, in main function.

Comment: @MisterSpock also, if you're using a c++ compiler you might as well use `std::vector` instead of arrays. Also, remove the `C` tag from your question, since C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @PeterT I'll go ahead and do that. This is part of the code written for CUDA C, where I originally had data in 2d vectors but had to convert to arrays. Even Thrust only takes 1d vectors.